# Falha ao criar Web Worker a partir de arquivo local no Chrome

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Ao tentar criar um worker

```
var worker = new Worker('teste.js');
```

recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at
>   'file:///C:/...../js/teste.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.

De a cordo com essa resposta no SOen, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23206866/5165064), não é possível carregar o arquivo local. Existe alguma forma alternativa de executar isso?

Obs: utilizo Google Chrome e Firefox

Comment: Um comentário na resposta lá está dizendo que o Firefox não tem problemas em carregar arquivos locais desde que seu script também seja local. Tentou isso?

Comment: Parece que no firefox roda mesmo, mas o problema é no Chorme, tenho que fazer rodas nos dois :s

Comment: Mas isso não é só para testes?

Comment: Sim mas pretendo implementar, mas se não funcionar nos navegadores principais fica complicado

Comment: Quando estiver hospedado num servidor vai funcionar. Isso só acontece localmente. Pode desenvolver no Firefox ou no Safari sem preocupações.

Comment: Fui testar no Firefox, ele da erro quando da um new Worker, retorna seguinte mensagem, `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.`

Comment: Eu publiquei uma resposta resumindo a solução para o problema geral com um link para um exemplo funcionando no Firefox. Fique à vontade para abrir uma nova pergunta para o seu caso específico, pois já estamos indo para outro rumo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Atualmente, há uma discordância entre os navegadores entre o que é considerado uma violação da política de mesma origem para os Workers. O Chrome e o Opera não permitem endereços locais mesmo rodando a partir de um script local, o que, na minha humilde opinião, é bobeira.

Enquanto isso não se resolve, o [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/developer/) dá suporte a executar Web Workers locais desde que a página esteja rodando também localmente. Isso pode ser verificado rodando [esse exemplo](https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker).
Repare que todos os caminhos são locais.

Se você tiver algum problema mesmo seguindo esses passos, publique uma nova pergunta específica para o seu caso com o código problemático.